# Shorthand version for javascript array condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I have 10 arrays of color styles in my JavaScript file. What I need is to check if the currently selected value in a dropdown list is equal to one of the array names I created, and assign the array once changed.

Here are 2 of the arrays:

```
var red = {
    primary_color: 'red',
    primary_hover_color: 'black',
    menu_color: '#9c9fa3'
}

var yellow = {
    primary_color: '#22c39b',
    primary_hover_color: '#187e65',
    menu_color: '#9c9fa3'
}
```

Then I also have this for the dropdown:

```
$('#color_palette').change(function() {
    var palette = $(this).val();

    if (palette = 'red') { palette = red }
    if (palette = 'yellow') { palette = yellow }
    // etc etc
});
```

I was wondering if there's a shorthand version of this instead of having to check an if condition for each value and make this more 'dynamic' rather than hardcode each color value in the condition.

Comment: Please, learn javascript first. Those are not arrays. The if has no boolean condition but assignments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to variable name in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm learning it, hence my question... and aren't they array objects?

Comment: @mousesports, No, they are just "objects".  Arrays use `[]` syntax.  Also, don't know why anyone is downvoting this question... it is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: They are objects. All arrays are objects, but not all objects are arrays.

Comment: Confusing but I'll get there! Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your colors in a single object

```
var colors = {
red: {
  primary_color: 'red',
  primary_hover_color: 'black',
  menu_color: '#9c9fa3'
},

yellow: {
  primary_color: '#22c39b',
  primary_hover_color: '#187e65',
  menu_color: '#9c9fa3'
}
}
```

Then change your check to

```
$('#color_palette').change(function() {
    var palette = colors[$(this).val()];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could arrange your palettes:

```
var palettes = {
   red: red,
   yellow: yellow
};
```

And then access them like so

```
var palette = palettes[palette];
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, lets fix the problems in the code you've posted;

1. What you have is not an array, it's an object declared via object literal syntax.
2. `if (palette = 'red')` is setting `palette` to `"red"`; it's not doing any comparison; thats `==` and `===`. What you *should* have is:

   ```
   if (palette === "red")
   ```
3. In your change handler you're overwriting your variable `palette` which contains the value the user selected with the contents of each `if` block.

   ```
   $('#color_palette').change(function() {
       var palette = $(this).val(); // <-- set here

       if (palette = 'red') { palette = red  // <--- overwritten here}
       if (palette = 'yellow' /* well, and here, but we fixed that in #2 */) { palette = yellow }
       // etc etc
   });
   ```

What you should look at doing is containing all of your color styles in a mother-object;

```
var styles = {
    red: {
        primary_color: 'red',
        primary_hover_color: 'black',
        menu_color: '#9c9fa3'
    },
    yellow: {
        primary_color: '#22c39b',
        primary_hover_color: '#187e65',
        menu_color: '#9c9fa3'
    }
};​
```

Then what you can do in your change function is simply:

```
$('#color_palette').change(function() {
    palette = styles[$(this).val()];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have an object of palettes:

```
palettes = {
    red: {
        primary_color: 'red',
        /* etc. */
    }, 
    yellow: {
         primary_color: 'yellow',
        /* etc. */
    }
}
```

Then, you could select it easily:

```
var selectedPalette = palettes[$(this).val()];
```