# Concactenate variable with id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to variable name in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

I have different variables (var1, var2, var3,.., to var10). I want to update them using a for loop like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
 var+i = i+20;
}
```

To obtain something like this:

```
var1 = 21;
var2 = 22;
var3 = 23;
...
var10 = 30;
```

My issue consists I can't concatenate the name of the variable with its id/position. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just ... don't ... do this.

Answer (score 6):

Use [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead of variables.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CBE8Q/)**

```
arr = []
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
 arr[i] = i+20;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Global variables (if that's what they are) are properties of the `window` object so you could do something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
    window["var"+i] = i+20;
}
```

Of course, I would recommend you use a different and simpler approach: arrays!

```
var data = [];
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
    data[i] = i+20;
}
```