# How to access text of select tag with respect to value?

Tags: javascript, html

suppose i have value 'v' in some variable say 'var', now i want to display Valvo(text respect to value v).
any suggestion??

Comment: There couldn't be a variable with name `var` :)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Are you trying to use String.substring()?

Comment: Do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript ?

Comment: @VisioN that was just an example...

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var myvar = 'b';

var elem = document.querySelector('#sel option[value^='+myvar.toUpperCase()+']');
if (typeof elem != 'undefined') {
  elem.selected = true;
}
```

Here you can test -> http://jsbin.com/ehayav/1

mz

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you :

```
//array of varables
var names = ['apple','banana','valvo','blahblahblah']
//this is your variable
var variable = 'v'
//code to display names starting with the character in your variable
for(i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    if(names[i][0] == variable)
        alert(names[i])
```

This answer is for my interpretation of your question. EnjoY!

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What you want to exactly do ?
Do you want to dynamically create a select box like this :
    '<select>
         <option value="a">Apple</option>
         <option value="b">Banana</option>
         <option value="v">Volvo</option>
         <option value="e">Exit</option>
     </select>'