# javascript output name of the variable, not the value

Tags: javascript, variables

how can I display string representation of a variable and not the value it contains.

I know eval can take string and evaluate to a variable but what's the other way?

Comment: What's the actual use case?

Comment: You got to show a basic example.

Comment: Show us the code, and an example of how you are trying to use it...

Comment: So you are saying that you have something like: var temp = 123; and you want to display "temp" instead of 123?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to variable name in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: That's a good question. I don't think it's even possible.

Comment: Duplicate of [Variable name as a string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript) I think

Comment: Here's the use case, I'm receiving a properties array in my callback function, that array enlists all properties of an object that has been changed, and array contains all those elements in string, wanna compare against actual properties against those strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are asking about property names, not variable names.

If you are getting an array of property names and you have a reference to the related object, you can use square bracket notation to access the named properties of the object:

```
var obj = {foo: '...', bar: '...', ...};
var propertyNames = ['foo', 'bar', ...];

for (var i=0, iLen=propertyNames.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (obj[propertyNames[i]] == someValue) {
      // do stuff

    } else {
      // do other stuff
    }
}
```