# Using a string to return a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way of using a string to refer to a variable.
Here is an example using jQuery:

```
var array = [1,2,3];

$('.array').click(function(){
    var foo = $(this).attr('class');
    return foo[1];
});
```

I want this to return the number '2' - 
but as foo is a string it will return the sub string 'r'.

edit - the answer I was looking for was:

```
var array = [1,2,3];

$('.array').click(function(){
    var foo = $(this).attr('class');
    return eval(foo)[1];
});
```

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to do?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up some major concepts here, please elaborate further on what, how and why you're trying to do.

Comment: From what's provided I don't see how it "obviously" returns 2 at all.

Comment: @Adjit the array OP created is called `array` and the return is `foo`

Comment: Oh yeah... my bad... serious case of skimming

Comment: I would assume class='[1,2,3]', maybe?

Comment: `$(this).attr('class');` is probably the string "`array`" (look at the jQuery selector with `.click`); OP wants to refer to the variable by name.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is quite what you mean, but a Javascript object can do this.:

```
foo = {}; // create object
foo["string"] = [1,2,3]; // now the list [1,2,3] can be referenced
                        //  by foo.string, or foo["string"]
console.log(foo["string"][1]); // Output with string.
```

Is that what you mean?