# how to convert ["one","two","three","four "] to [one,two,thee,four] as array in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario. I will get all the data from service in the below shown array format.
but I need to convert that to by removing them as strings

```
var array1 = ["one","two","three","four"]

var array1 =  [one,two,thee,four]
```

array contains strings to variables of the array.

Comment: array accept object and if you don't want `"one","two"..` and `one,two..` then `one`, `two` should be a variable or object.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It sounds very much like you need an object.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
var array1 = ["one","two","three","four"].map(function(val){ return window[val]; });
```

But the new array would contain the values of the variables not the variable itself.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant look up basically starts from local scope to the global scope.

Comment: just replace `window` with `this` and it does  :)

Comment: @elclanrs Yes.. Just now realised that.. thought in a different way. Ok then to overcome that then we must use eval() at this context. Am i right.??

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: I'd have to know why OP wants to do this to tell what's the right solution; both this and `eval` are questionable solutions to a problem that shouldn't exist.

Comment: yes it does. I ment like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/m3m0xrs2/) It's just basic scoping

Answer (score 0):

There are no double quotes in that array. The quotes just delimit the `string` literals, when they are parsed into strings they don't have quotes in them.

---

If you wanted to remove all the quotes from a string which actually had some in it:

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, "");  // RegEx to match `"` characters, with `g` for globally (instead of once)
```

You could do that in a loop over an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = array1[i].replace(/"/g, "");
}
```