# Create a variable named after a string parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know this piece of code is wrong, but I wonder if there is any way this would be possible.

```
var createVariableFromParameter = function(myName) {

  var myName = [];
  return myName;
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I found the solution here: [Convert string to variable name in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It's not obvious from your code. You're taking an argument, overriding it completely, and then returning it.

Comment: why didn't you ask in the first place about what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, and even if it could be done, why would you want to do it? There is no meaning in creating variables with random names...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you should need it??
But I think true way is :

```
function create(myvar) { myvar = [];}

var a;
create(a);

function create() { return [];}

var b = new create();
```