# Javascript - Create new variable each time function is called

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is create a new variable each time function `loadGrid` is called. In the function below, the variable in this case would be `datagrid`. The reason why I want to do this is because I'll be creating multiple table objects, and each table object will need its own reference variable to call functions such as `filter` to it.

I looked into this solution here: [Convert string to variable name in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript). However, comments state this isn't best practice in Javascript. Is there a better solution to what I want to achieve?

```
var loadGrid = function(dbTableName) {

    $('#'+dbTableName).on('click', function(e){

        $('#tables').find('.active').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        DatabaseGrid.prototype.fetchGrid = function()  {
            // call the PHP script to get the data
            this.editableGrid.loadJSON("loaddatacustomers.php?db_tablename=" + dbTableName);
        };

        var datagrid = new DatabaseGrid();

        $("#filter").keyup(function() {
          datagrid.editableGrid.filter( $(this).val());
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Since essentially everybody in the world thinks that global variables are bad things, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Don't use separate variables. Use an array. Each time you call the function, you `.push()` a new element onto the array.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry I don't necessarily need to create a global variable. I just need to create a new reference variable for each new `DatabaseGrid` object created so I can use functions such as `filter` on it.

Comment: @jchi2241 You could `return datagrid;` or an object containing it, and let the other code manage the references.

Comment: @Barmar Every time the grid is reloaded, this will create a new object. If the grid is reloaded multiple times, this will create multiple references in that one array until the page is refreshed. Is there a way to just replace that reference in the array instead of continuously pushing new objects into it?

Comment: Isn't that what you want? If you were going to create a new variable, what's wrong with creating a new array element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create an array that holds all your datagrids!

```
datagridSet = [];
loadGrid = function(dbTableName){
    (..)
    var datagrid = new DatabaseGrid();
    datagridSet.push(datagrid);
    (..)
}
```

You would access each datagrid via the `Array[index]` notation :)

Also, global variables are not a very good idea, for that you could create your own pseudo-namespace.

```
GridStuff = {
    datagridSet:[],
    loadGrid:function(dbTableName){
        (..)
        var datagrid = new DatabaseGrid();
        this.datagridSet.push(datagrid);
        (..)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, happy new year!