# is there a way to declare a variable using the value of a functions parameter

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I need to declare a variable using a name that is sent through a function
as a parameter/argument

```
function CreateDroptable(npcName) {
    Droptable.npcName = new Droptable();
}
```

what I want this to do is if typed "CreateDroptable(goblin)"
it would create the variable "Droptable.goblin"
but instead it declares it like "Droptable.npcName"

Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CreateDroptable(npcName) {
    Droptable[npcName] = new Droptable();
}
```

should do the trick. String/array/bracket notation is there for this very reason. :)

Edit:

I noticed that you mentioned using it accordingly: `CreateDroptable(goblin)` which will not work as is. it should be utilized like so:

```
CreateDroptable("goblin");
```

where goblin is a string, rather than a variable.

Comment: @jonaskjellerup could you repost the error you're getting? It didn't show up when you commented.

Comment: found the problem is that i forgot to remove the "." before the "[" but again gives the same problem as the solution below

Comment: @jonaskjellerup I'm not sure I understand the problem, what is the array you are referring to? All this does is creates a key on your current `Droptable` object with the value being a new Droptable object.

Comment: The arrays are in the object Droptable but i figured out the problem with that

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
function CreateDroptable(npcName) {
  Dreoptable[npcName] = new Droptable();
}
```

Then, when declaring ...

```
CreateDroptable("goblin");
```

Calling becomes ...

```
Droptable["goblin"](1,2,3);
```

Comment: this kinda works but it doesn't because the Droptable is a object and this solution makes the arrays work as normal variables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use straight objects instead of variables/arrays. Then you have to go object-orientated route - which is a bit different to what you have done.

```
function npc(type, health, strength) {
    this.type= type;
    this.health= health;
    this.strength= strength;
}

var goblin= new npc("Goblin", 100, 50);
var bat = new npc("Bat", 65, 1);
```

This overall looks a lot cleaner, and is the conventional way of doing things. But it may not be entirely what you are looking for.

Hope it helps nonetheless.

Happy coding!