# Can't get typeof of a string evaluated with eval()

Tags: javascript, string, object, eval, typeof

I'm trying to get the type of of a string evaluated with `eval()` with no success.

The variable is a string stored in an array with the name of a possible object which I want to know if is defined.

Can someone give a hand please?

The troubling line is `if ( typeof eval( x[i][0] ) !== 'undefined' )` and this is my code:

```
    var infoslider = [
    ["revapi5", "el-masnou", "sant-andreu-de-llavaneres"],
    ["revapi3", "sant-andreu-de-llavaneres", "cardedeu"],
    ["revapi10", "cardedeu", "eudald-carbonell"],
    ["revapi9", "arenys-de-mar", "canet-de-mar"]
];
var x = infoslider;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if ( typeof eval( x[i][0] ) !== 'undefined' ) {
        vesa(x[i][0], x[i][2]);
    }
}
```

I get "ReferenceError: revapi5 is not defined"

Comment: What makes you think you need or want `eval` there?

Comment: *"The variable is a string stored in an array with the name of a possible object which I want to know if is defined."* Not quite following. Are you saying you may or may not have a variable called (for instance) `revapi5`?

Comment: [I've answered what you actually asked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29700479/157247), I think, but this seems like the "X/Y problem": You need to solve X, and you think Y will help you do that, but you're having trouble doing Y and asked how to do Y -- but if we knew what X was, we could probably suggest a better solution than Y. :-)

Comment: I want to know if revapi5 is actually an defined object. In fact I want to simplify a code that checks if this object is defined. The initial code is:
    if (typeof revapi3 !== 'undefined') {
            vesa(revapi3, 'el-masnou')
            // Masnou
        } else if (typeof revapi5 !== 'undefined') {
            vesa(revapi5, 'arenys-de-mar')
            // Entrevista Carbonell
        } else if (typeof revapi6 !== 'undefined') {
            vesa(revapi6, 'arenys-de-mar')
            // Cementiri Arenys de Mar
        }// end if typeof

Comment: My answer tells you how to do that, but again, it's the X/Y thing: ***Why*** do you want to know if `revapi5` is a declared variable? Where does it come from? Is it a global? A local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The variable is a string stored in an array with the name of a possible object which I want to know if is defined.

If you mean that there may or may not be a variable named `revapi5` **declared** and it will have a value other than `undefined` if it is declared, and you want to know whether it is, you *could* move the `typeof` *into* the string you're `eval`'ing:

```
if ( eval( "typeof " + x[i][0] ) !== 'undefined' ) {
```

***But***, there's almost certainly a better way to solve whatever the problem is that you're trying to solve by doing that.

Example of the above:

```js
var revapi5 = {}; // We do have 5, but we don't have the others
var infoslider = [
  ["revapi5", "el-masnou", "sant-andreu-de-llavaneres"],
  ["revapi3", "sant-andreu-de-llavaneres", "cardedeu"],
  ["revapi10", "cardedeu", "eudald-carbonell"],
  ["revapi9", "arenys-de-mar", "canet-de-mar"]
];
var x = infoslider;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (eval("typeof " + x[i][0]) !== 'undefined') {
    snippet.log(x[i][0] + " is declared and has a value other than undefined");
  } else {
    snippet.log(x[i][0] + " is either undeclared, or has the value undefined");
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Siguza: Thanks -- meant to *move* `typeof` rather than adding a second one, just fixed it when adding a live example.

Comment: @T.J Crowder It works!
That's the final code:
         var infoslider = [
        ["revapi5", "el-masnou", "sant-andreu-de-llavaneres"],
        ["revapi3", "sant-andreu-de-llavaneres", "cardedeu"],
        ["revapi10", "cardedeu", "eudald-carbonell"],
        ["revapi9", "arenys-de-mar", "canet-de-mar"]
    ];
    var x = infoslider;
    var z = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if ( eval ( "typeof " + x[i][0] ) !== 'undefined' ) {
            vesa(eval(x[i][0]), x[i][2]);
        }
    }
DanielM your code also worked but I prefer to avoid globals.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use eval, try this:

```
typeof window[ x[i][0] ] !== 'undefined'
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

**Update:**

If your variables are not stored globally, you can swap `window` for whatever object they're stored in (assuming it's in scope)... if it's the same object then `this` should work.

Also @vol7ron made a better suggestion of using `.hasOwnPropery` rather than checking for undefined.

Comment: That will only work if these variables are globals. Globals are, of course, best avoided, so...

Comment: And if you're going to use globals, you might as well just do `if ( window.hasOwnProperty(x[i][0]) ) { ... }`

Comment: That's more of a preference thing for readability.  `hasOwnProperty` suggests looking for the existence.  However, it's important to note that `typeof` would be much more efficient; so if every microsecond of performance is an issue, or if this is going to be put in a loop, that could matter.  I haven't seen the need for this level of optimization since needing to write a super resource intensive application to be able to run on early version of smartphones.  So it's better to be more readable for maintainability.

Comment: Yeah, I guess saying "better" is subjective, but for those of us who hate programatically dealing with strings (which actually is what this question is about) as it hides functionality, `.hasOwnProperty` is preferable. IDE's will additionally help prevent you getting a typo in that too. :p