# How do I set a variabels value as a new variable?

Tags: javascript

As in if I have `var x = "foo"` and I need to create a new variable called `foo` by using `x`. Like `var "valueOf(x)" =` ... or something. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: If I understand your questions, it seems to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript - hope this helps!

Comment: @Jackson — The question is asking how to use the value of a variable as the name of another variable, not how to give two variables the same value.

Comment: What Im trying to accomplish is this: I have a variable that's is set to name and then another variable set to its value, I want to combine these two, the name with the value as in: var name = value

Comment: @Ferus — Yes, that's what the duplicate question explains how to do.

Comment: Alright, didn't see that post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = "foo";
window[x] = 'hi';
alert(foo);
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qszscfLk/

Comment: That only works with globals … and globals should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

What scope are these variables in? If they are on the window (global context ) you can use the bracket notation  call `window[x] = bar` and will now have a bar variable available. 
If it's in a function it would be more clear to use `this` instead of window

Comment: In that case use `this[x] = 'bar'` and now the local variable foo will be available in that function and equal to bar