# Find Data from adding dynamic collection name in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to pass collection name in req.body and query the collection with that name .I tried this but its not working in mongoose

```
router.get('/data',(req,res)=>{
var mySchema="User"; // i will get it from req.body.model
    mySchema.find({},(err,docs)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        res.json({
            success:true,
            data:docs
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really not encourage this practice but you can use `eval()`

```
var mySchema = "User";
eval(mySchema).find({},(err, docs) => {...
```

You can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5613834/5156280) for more precision

Comment: Thanks its working, actually what i want is that in this route i am sending a keyword, and i want to check that keyword in all collections and based on that response is sent.. so not to query all collections, i am also sending collection name from req.body ....please provide another soultion of my problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but it seems that you should rethink your application structure. For a multi collection search, maybe _$lookup_ aggregation could help.

Comment: @GauravUmrani I need to set the collection name dynamic for executing queries... I tried the above provided solution... but it showed me below error 
**TypeError: eval is not a constructor**

Can we get other solution or get this above code working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above provided solution, as shown in the snippet below

```
let colName = 'users';
const dbModelObj = new eval(colName)(dataSet);
```

however it displayed error as below

> TypeError: eval is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why users above suggested use only eval. There is another way, by creating model dynamically.

```
let dynamicModels = {};
const schema = new Schema({}, {versionKey : false, strict: false});

const dynamicModel = (collection) => {
    if( !(collection in dynamicModels) ){
        dynamicModels[name] = connection.model(collection, schema, collection);
    }
    return dynamicModels[collectionName];
};
```

then you can use

```
const user = dynamicModel("user").findOne({})
```