# concatenate strings to make variable

Tags: javascript

I have a variable multiple variables that end differently such as

```
fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixings

fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixingsprice

fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixingsunits

fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixingsrange
```

I'm looking for a way to be able to just use the main variable then add the last part on where needed in the function something like

fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixings + price would print the value of fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixingsprice

Comment: You probably want to use arrays - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to variable name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: use `eval` on a string

Comment: "*I have a variable multiple variables*" - that's the actual problem you need to fix. Not finding a way to access them. Use an object.

Comment: In hindsight I should have used an array instead, I guess it could be worth the effort to go though and change them all.

Comment: Try `window["fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixings" + "price"] = 123`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're looking for is **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**:

```js
var fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixingsprice = 23;
console.log(eval("fibrecementrustedorpoppedfixings" + "price"));
```

**However**, note that `eval()` [can be **evil**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil), as it:

- requires a compile (and is therefore slow)
- can execute malicious arguments
- inherits execution scope

As such, it should only be used with caution.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That looks to work perfect thanks! I shall look more into eval() though