# How can i join a string and a variable to create a new variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, for-loop, addeventlistener

Found a couple of solutions for php, but couldn't find any for javascript.

Basically I am trying to make a bunch of eventlisteners for 30 buttons i have on my page. Currently it is written out like this :

```
problem1buttonEl.addEventListener("click", problem1);
problem2buttonEl.addEventListener("click", problem2);
problem3buttonEl.addEventListener("click", problem3);
problem4buttonEl.addEventListener("click", problem4);
```

Now I want to make a for loop to make this cleaner, something like this:

```
for (var problemIncrement = 1; problemIncrement <= 30; problemIncrement++) {
'problem' + problemIncrement + 'buttonEl'.addEventListener("click", 
'problem' + problemIncrement);
}
```

The problem is that i need to add a string to my variable and have the outcome of them also be a variable, as that is what problemXbuttonEl is.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: how do you create the *n* functions?

Comment: so you need an array of all your answers and then split it out into a string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the brackets notation `[]` to get these variables, normally they should be defined in the `window` object so this is how should be your code:

```
for (var problemIncrement = 1; problemIncrement <= 30; problemIncrement++) {
    window['problem' + problemIncrement + 'buttonEl'].addEventListener("click", 
    window['problem' + problemIncrement]);
}
```

Here `window['problem' + problemIncrement + 'buttonEl']` will refer to the varibale you already defined.

Comment: Well u sir just cut out 143 lines of code, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a closure with an argument for the number of the identifier for the button like

```
function problem(n) {
    return function () {
        // do something with n
    }
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    getElementById('problem' + i + 'buttonEl').addEventListener("click", problem(i));
}
```

Comment: Ah thats a smart integration of the getElemtById part too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultsArray = [1, 2, 3];
var resultsString = myArray.join();
problem1buttonEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  resultsArray.push(problem1)
});

document.write(resultsString);
```

or something like that!