# How to check if value is the same as imported class name

Tags: javascript

I have some data in a class that is imported to be used when a variable name is the same as the imported class name. I don't know the best way to first check the value if its the same as the imported class name.

Right now my code looks like:

```
import { TEST, TEST2 } from '../shared/panel';

selectPanel(panel) {
  let test;
  if(panel === 'TEST'){
    test = TEST;
  }   
  else if(panel === 'TEST2'){
    test = TEST2;
  }
  else{
    test = '';
  }
}
```

Is there any shorter way or better way to do this? Cause when there are lots of condition it become messy.

Comment: use a switch statement

Comment: @DerekPollard hmm, not really what I expected. since the value of the class name and the value to be compared is the same, is there any way to write it better way?

Comment: `'TEST' and TEST` aren't the same though; One is a value and the other is a variable name

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript

Comment: if your vars aren't in the global namespace, you better read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval before going the eval route

Comment: @DerekPollard its is the same in terms of the names, which is answered by El Aoutar Hamza below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import all the variables this way:

```
import * as panels from '../shared/panel';
```

Now you will have an object (`panels`) that has your variables *names* as keys.

So you can do something like:

```
const selectPanel = key => panels[key] || ""
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
selectPanel(panel) {
  let test;
  if(window[panel]=="undefined"){
    test = '';
  }
  else{
  test = window[panel]
  }
}
```

I didn't test but i think it will work

Comment: This will assume that all the variables (`TEST`, `TEST2` ..) are global

Comment: Yeah, my variables are not global