# How do i convert a string to a variable in javascript without using eval() or window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dexie

I am having problems converting a string to a variable.

- I cannot use an `eval()` because the code is ran through another `eval`
- I have no access to `window`.

I have tried running an IIFE function  no success

[I have tried these stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

How do i convert a string to a variable?

**For clarity why**

```js
myObject = {
  name: 'alexander',
  color: 'grey'
}

for (const key of Object.keys(myObject)) {
        db.friends.update(2, {
          key: "Test data"})

      }
```

A workaround to this could also be helpful.

Could I trim?

Comment: i could use if statements on `key` but that would mean i would have to repeat the same `query` several times which is what amt trying to avoid

Comment: Not sure what the example should demonstrate. Do you want to have a dynamic property name? `{[column]: "Test data"}` or maybe `{[key]: "Test data"}`. A property is not a variable though, which is why it's unclear how the code relates to the description of your problem. You are not doing anything with `key`, so it's unclear to me how you intend to use it.

Comment: What is the input string, and what is the desired output?